# Change android App drawer icon won't change from default

Tags: android, icons, manifest

How do I make the icon change from the default icon?  My custom icon (called launcherrounded, clever I know) shows up when i put a shortcut on the home screen but when I look at it in the app drawer it shows up as the default icon.

I'm not sure but I would assume the problem lies somewhere in my manifest...

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/launcherrounded" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".MainScreen"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".WorkoutActivity"
    >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".WorkoutDbAdapter"
    >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TimerActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GraphScreen">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Preferences"
    android:label="@string/set_preferences">
    </activity>
    <receiver
    android:name=".OnAlarmReceiver"></receiver>
        <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"></service>

</application>
```

EDIT: Figured it out, had to uninstall and reinstall and then it showed up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it be uninstalling and reinstalling.  APparently just updating it doesn't work you have to uninstall.

I guess the App drawer icon is set at install, good to know...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put android:icon on the activity too.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that on your device, it's using the drawable-hdpi version of your icon in one place, and the drawable-mdpi version of it in another place.

You can just delete any version of the icon except the one in drawable-hdpi. Then Android will just downscale it whenever necessary.  When you actually release the app, you might want to create a mdpi version of the icon to avoid scaling artifacts. In my opinion, ldpi is not really worth bothering with, but you can do that too.